# JSHint + Flymake - infinite loop error checking

Tags: emacs, jshint, flymake

I've tried to figure the problem myself, and will probably continue, but due to poor error reporting it's just too time consuming. So, perhaps, if anyone had encountered this problem before, please share.

What happens: after flymake-jshint encounters an error, no matter what the error is, it could be a missing semicolon for example. It will get stuck in an infinite loop. I can <kbd>C-g</kbd> the loop, but this is very annoying, and will happen multiple times on the same line, making it absolutely impossible to write anything.

When I then look into the `*Messages*` buffer, it reveals something like:

```
missing ; after statement [NNNN times]
```

i.e Flymake was requested to perform the check many times. The timer interval is set to 2 seconds, but it clearly overdoes, because it will do hundreds of checks in two seconds. Trying to increase the `flymake-log-level` reveals no additional information.

I have customized these variables:

```
(flymake-no-changes-timeout 2)
(flymake-start-syntax-check-on-newline nil)
```

but no more additional customizations.

**EDIT:**

This seems to be related to auto-complete mode. Disabling this minor mode "solved" the problem, but now I'm getting hundreds of "Invalid face reference: nil [NNNN times]" kinds of messages. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I think, I finally found the problem. It was the `highlight-current-line` minor mode. Whenever Flymake would detect an error and needed to paint the error location it tried to read the overlay, but got confused by the overlay created by the highlight. I haven't yet gotten to trying to fix it, but simple disabling of the highlight made it at least possible to work.